# Method not getting invoked

Tags: java, python

I have some experience using Python so I've been trying to learn Java by writing the same programs I write in Python for school in Java.

I have this function where I enter two integers and it returns the sum. If the integers are the same, then it returns double the sum. For example, 5 + 5 = 20.
I have the following code for this function.

```
public class sumDouble
{
   public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
       int sum = a + b;

       if (a == b) {
           sum = sum * 2;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Next, I want to write a script where I ask the user to input two integers and the main class calls this function. I have the following code for this. Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GetSumFromUser
{
  public static void main (String[] args){

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int a;
      int b;
      int sumDouble;
      sumDouble sum = new sumDouble();

      System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered "+a);

      System.out.println("Please enter another integer.");
      b = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered "+b);

      System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum);

    }
}
```

At the last line, the output reads "Your sum is sumDouble@1777aec".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `print(sum)` then  you are printing the object...

do instead

`System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum.sumDouble(a,b));`

Answer (score 1):

You never actually invoked the `sumDouble()` method. Rather than print out `sum` (which is an `Object`), you should print like this:

```
System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum.sumDouble(a,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class SumDouble
{
   public static int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
       int sum = a + b;

       if (a == b) {
           sum = sum * 2;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

...

System.out.println("Your sum is "+SumDouble.sumDouble(a, b));
```

Comment: Yes, since `sumDouble()` doesn't change the state of the containing class, there's no reason it can't be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You get an object from `sumDouble` class, but you never invoke it's `sumDouble` method:

```
sumDouble sum = new sumDouble();
```

change this to:

```
sumDouble sd = new sumDouble();
int sum = sd.sumDouble(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package test;

    import java.util.Scanner;

     class sumDouble
{
    public  int sumDouble(int a,int b)
        {
            int sum=a+b;                 //add the numbers
            if(a==b)                     //check if both numbers are same
                sum=sum*2;              //double th value if same
            return sum;                 //return sum
        }
}

    public class GetSumFromUser
    {


      public static void main (String[] args){

          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    sumDouble s=new sumDouble();
          int a;
          int b;
          int sum;

          System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
          a = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("You entered "+a);

          System.out.println("Please enter another integer.");
          b = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("You entered "+b);
       sum= s.sumDouble(a, b) ;                    //call the sum double function

          System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum);
```

Change this to:

```
System.out.println("Your sum is "+sum.sumDouble(a,b));
```

You haven't called the method. "Your sum is "+sum  -this will call the toString method of sum which is sumDouble@1777aec.